# how to click on an element until it is appearing (Cypress)

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, automation, cypress

I need to click on pop-ups until they appearing. But there is the issue because on the different tabs in the application I have to click in them different number of times.

In python i just used loop with if and else, whenever some particular locator appeared I clicked in it, and when it is not present anymore I used else pass.

There is any solution in Cypress how can I click in a pop-up 4,5 or 6 times with if/else and continue test suite performing when a pop-up is not present anymore?

Maybe something with if-return, else-expect?

```
Cypress.Commands.add("acceptPopup", () => {
    for (let n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
        if (cy.xpath('//button[contains(@title,"Last")]', {
                timeout: 100000
            }).should("be.visible")) {
            return cy.xpath('//button[contains(@title,"Last")]').click();
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code that you tried and also add the HTML of your webpage

Comment: Cypress.Commands.add("acceptPopup", () => {
  for (let n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
    if (
      cy
        .xpath('//button[contains(@title,"Last")]', { timeout: 100000 })
        .should("be.visible")
    ) {
       return cy.xpath('//button[contains(@title,"Last")]').click();
    }
  }
});

Sorry for the format, don't know how to format it in the comment structure